# I can't run my node server Babel compilation error

Tags: node.js, express, babeljs

I'm following this [tutorial](https://codingthesmartway.com/angular-6-mean-stack-crash-course-part-2-implementing-the-back-end/) for a MEAN stack and I can't run my server I get this error

> Babel compilation error TypeError: Cannot read property 'bindings'

Here is my [repo](https://github.com/Maydara86/backend-node)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial you are following must be a little old. You'd need to add `@babel/core` and `@babel/preset-env` as dev dependencies in your application.

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/preset-env
```

You'd also need to replace contents of `.babelrc` file with following as @iLuvLogix pointed out.

```
{ "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"] }
```

Please note that `server.js` that babel-watch looks for, seems to be missing in your repo. You'd need to create that, since that's the first file (as per your package.json) that gets executed when you start your server.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using babel 7.x, try changing your `.babelrc` file to

```
{ "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"] }
```

If you are referencing the package `babel-preset-env` in your `.babelrc` (which is for 6.x), you want to reference `@babel/preset-env` instead (which is for 7.x).

Here's the report of this issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/6186#issuecomment-366556833)